# Dual of $L^p$ when $p = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

I've spent some time searching for this online - both on this site and elsewhere - and even after consulting a considerable amount of literature, I can't seem to nail down an answer. Perhaps someone can help me.

Suppose I'm dealing with the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\Sigma,\mu)$ where $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets and where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. It's a relatively standard exercise to show that the dual of $L^p$ is $L^q$ where $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ when $1\leq p<\infty$; one can also show that the dual of $L^\infty$ is (in Royden's notation) $\mathcal{BFA}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ (i.e.the normed linear space of finitely additive signed measures on $\Sigma$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$). Finally, in the case of $0 < p < 1$, the dual of $L^p$ is trivial (i.e., is equal to $\{0\}$); this is shown in any number of papers (e.g., by Day, Conrad, Rosenzweig, etc.). This brings me to my question:

If we write $L^0$ for the space of all measurable functions on the measure space in question, do we know what the dual is? I've read about ba-spaces and the dual of $B(\Sigma)$ (that is, the space of all bounded $\Sigma$-measurable functions with the uniform norm) but that info doesn't work here. Also, a MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602050/dual-space-of-a-complete-vector-space) discusses something which may be related, but my knowledge of probability-related measure theory is scant.

Any information and/or direction to online resources discussing this would be hugely appreciated.

**Edit** - Per the comment of @Ian below, the topology I'm considering on $L^0$ is the topology induced by convergence in measure as mentioned in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#L0.2C_the_space_of_measurable_functions).

Comment: @Ian - Perhaps I should have asked as well: Is there a "more natural" topology for $L^0$? I know the other $L^p$ spaces tend to have "natural topologies" that we talk about when discussing continuous duals; is it correct to assume that the topology induced by convergence in measure is the most natural? Or is there no natural one?

Comment: To my (limited) understanding, the topology of convergence in measure is a bit subtle. For instance, in a finite measure space it is metrizable; in an infinite measure space it is not metrizable.

Comment: I think there are no nontrivial continuous linear functionals. Try adapting the proof for $L^p$, $0<p<1$, to  measurable functions on  $[0,1]$ with the metric $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f-g|/(1+|f-g|)$. (If there was a continuous linear functional on $L^0(\mathbb R)$, it would induce one on $L^0([0,1])$.)

Comment: @Fundamental - Thanks for your response! I believe that adapting the proof as you mentioned is easy enough to do, though my question is (perhaps ignorantly): Why does it suffice to only consider the metric you mentioned?